# Write xml file using spring integration one message at one time

Tags: xml, spring, spring-integration

```
I am using Spring Integration to implement a solution where i have to read file and search some data in other file and then i need to write on xml file .

1)I have created integration flow like that :

    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow fileIntegrationFlow(){
        return IntegrationFlows.from(readFilefromDirectory(), fileInboundPollingConsumer())
                .split(new FileSplitter())
                .transform(dataDataTransformer())
                .transform(Transformers.marshaller(getMarshaller(),resultTransformer(),true))
                .wireTap(logChannel())
                .handle(fileWriter()).get();

    }

2)File writer i have configured below like that :

    @Bean
    public FileWritingMessageHandler fileWriter() {
        FileWritingMessageHandler writer = new FileWritingMessageHandler(
                new File("D://example_tex//write"));
        writer.setExpectReply(false);
        writer.setFileExistsMode(FileExistsMode.APPEND);
        writer.setAppendNewLine(true);
        writer.setFileNameGenerator(fileNameGenerator());
        return writer;
    }

3)I have configured marshaller like that :

    @Bean
    public Marshaller getMarshaller(){
        Jaxb2Marshaller marshaller = new Jaxb2Marshaller();
        marshaller.setPackagesToScan("com.springintegration.example");
        return marshaller;
    }

4)I have used Result transformer below like this :


    @Bean
    public ResultTransformer resultTransformer() {
        ResultToStringTransformer resultToStringTransformer= new ResultToStringTransformer();
        Properties p = new Properties();
        p.setProperty(OutputKeys.OMIT_XML_DECLARATION, "yes");
        resultToStringTransformer.setOutputProperties(p);
        return resultToStringTransformer;

    }

So above is my configuration for Spring Integration flow .
My Question is Below :

1)After splitting one message flow goes further and it is processed and written in file .But in xml file while writing where should i configure header and footer so that it is written once and proper xml file is generated .
```

I have customer object which is list in monitoringdata object . i need to create xml file for this object .
@XmlRootElement
public class MonitoringData {

```
List<Customer> customerList ;

public List<Customer> getCustomerList() {
    return customerList;
}

public void setCustomerList(List<Customer> customerList) {
    this.customerList = customerList;
}
```

}

```
Final Xml file after all customer object added in file Shoul look like this.
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<MonitoringData xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="java:java.lang.String">
<customer><cust-name>33334444</cust-name></customer>
<customer><cust-name>3333333</cust-name></customer>
</MonitoringData>
```

I am able to write customer object part and it is writing one by one But how Monitoringdata object to add and xml header in output file.

UPDATED CODE FLOW :
I have created flow like this but file is not getting created : Do i miss something .

```
@Bean
    public IntegrationFlow fileIntegrationFlow(){
        return IntegrationFlows.from(readFilefromDirectory(), fileInboundPollingConsumer())
                .split(new FileSplitter())
                .transform(dataDataTransformer())
                .wireTap(logChannel())
                .aggregate()
                .<List<Customer>>handle((p, h) -> new MonitoringData(p))
    .transform(Transformers.marshaller(getMarshaller(),resultTransformer(),true))
                .handle(fileWriter()).get();

    }
```

DATA TRANSFORMER :

```
@MessageEndpoint
public class DataTransformer {


    @Transformer
    public Customer transferData(String payload){
        Customer customer = new Customer();
        customer.setCustName(payload);
        return customer;
    }
```

LOGS:

```
  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v1.2.4.RELEASE)

2016-09-15 01:21:21.242  INFO 6672 --- [           main] c.s.e.FileIntegrationFlowConfiguration   : Starting FileIntegrationFlowConfiguration on Amar with PID 6672 (C:\Users\Amar.Singh\workspace\SpringIntegration\target\classes started by Amar.Singh in C:\Users\Amar.Singh\workspace\SpringIntegration)
2016-09-15 01:21:21.286  INFO 6672 --- [           main] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@71a794e5: startup date [Thu Sep 15 01:21:21 CEST 2016]; root of context hierarchy
2016-09-15 01:21:22.194  INFO 6672 --- [           main] o.s.b.f.config.PropertiesFactoryBean     : Loading properties file from URL [jar:file:/C:/Users/Amar.Singh/.m2/repository/org/springframework/integration/spring-integration-core/4.3.1.RELEASE/spring-integration-core-4.3.1.RELEASE.jar!/META-INF/spring.integration.default.properties]
2016-09-15 01:21:22.199  INFO 6672 --- [           main] o.s.i.config.IntegrationRegistrar        : No bean named 'integrationHeaderChannelRegistry' has been explicitly defined. Therefore, a default DefaultHeaderChannelRegistry will be created.
2016-09-15 01:21:22.211  INFO 6672 --- [           main] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Overriding bean definition for bean 'dataTransformer' with a different definition: replacing [Generic bean: class [com.springintegration.example.DataTransformer]; scope=singleton; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null; defined in file [C:\Users\Amar.Singh\workspace\SpringIntegration\target\classes\com\springintegration\example\DataTransformer.class]] with [Root bean: class [null]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=3; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=serviceIntegrationFlowConfiguration; factoryMethodName=dataTransformer; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=(inferred); defined in class path resource [com/springintegration/example/ServiceIntegrationFlowConfiguration.class]]
2016-09-15 01:21:22.231  INFO 6672 --- [           main] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Overriding bean definition for bean 'logFlow' with a different definition: replacing [Root bean: class [null]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=3; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=serviceIntegrationFlowConfiguration; factoryMethodName=logFlow; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=(inferred); defined in class path resource [com/springintegration/example/ServiceIntegrationFlowConfiguration.class]] with [Root bean: class [null]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=3; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=fileIntegrationFlowConfiguration; factoryMethodName=logFlow; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=(inferred); defined in com.springintegration.example.FileIntegrationFlowConfiguration]
2016-09-15 01:21:22.233  INFO 6672 --- [           main] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Overriding bean definition for bean 'logChannel' with a different definition: replacing [Root bean: class [null]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=3; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=serviceIntegrationFlowConfiguration; factoryMethodName=logChannel; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=(inferred); defined in class path resource [com/springintegration/example/ServiceIntegrationFlowConfiguration.class]] with [Root bean: class [null]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=3; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=fileIntegrationFlowConfiguration; factoryMethodName=logChannel; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=(inferred); defined in com.springintegration.example.FileIntegrationFlowConfiguration]
2016-09-15 01:21:22.328  INFO 6672 --- [           main] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Overriding bean definition for bean 'beanNameViewResolver' with a different definition: replacing [Root bean: class [null]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=3; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.ErrorMvcAutoConfiguration$WhitelabelErrorViewConfiguration; factoryMethodName=beanNameViewResolver; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=(inferred); defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/ErrorMvcAutoConfiguration$WhitelabelErrorViewConfiguration.class]] with [Root bean: class [null]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=3; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.WebMvcAutoConfiguration$WebMvcAutoConfigurationAdapter; factoryMethodName=beanNameViewResolver; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=(inferred); defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/WebMvcAutoConfiguration$WebMvcAutoConfigurationAdapter.class]]
2016-09-15 01:21:22.743  INFO 6672 --- [           main] faultConfiguringBeanFactoryPostProcessor : No bean named 'errorChannel' has been explicitly defined. Therefore, a default PublishSubscribeChannel will be created.
2016-09-15 01:21:22.747  INFO 6672 --- [           main] faultConfiguringBeanFactoryPostProcessor : No bean named 'taskScheduler' has been explicitly defined. Therefore, a default ThreadPoolTaskScheduler will be created.
2016-09-15 01:21:23.031  INFO 6672 --- [           main] o.s.b.f.config.PropertiesFactoryBean     : Loading properties file from URL [jar:file:/C:/Users/Amar.Singh/.m2/repository/org/springframework/integration/spring-integration-core/4.3.1.RELEASE/spring-integration-core-4.3.1.RELEASE.jar!/META-INF/spring.integration.default.properties]
2016-09-15 01:21:23.032  INFO 6672 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'integrationGlobalProperties' of type [class org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertiesFactoryBean] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2016-09-15 01:21:23.037  INFO 6672 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'integrationGlobalProperties' of type [class java.util.Properties] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2016-09-15 01:21:23.581  INFO 6672 --- [           main] s.b.c.e.t.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2016-09-15 01:21:23.933  INFO 6672 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service Tomcat
2016-09-15 01:21:23.935  INFO 6672 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.0.23
2016-09-15 01:21:24.095  INFO 6672 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2016-09-15 01:21:24.095  INFO 6672 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 2811 ms
2016-09-15 01:21:24.377  INFO 6672 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : Initializing ExecutorService  'metricsExecutor'
2016-09-15 01:21:25.181  INFO 6672 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.c.e.ServletRegistrationBean        : Mapping servlet: 'dispatcherServlet' to [/]
2016-09-15 01:21:25.185  INFO 6672 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.c.embedded.FilterRegistrationBean  : Mapping filter: 'metricFilter' to: [/*]
2016-09-15 01:21:25.186  INFO 6672 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.c.embedded.FilterRegistrationBean  : Mapping filter: 'characterEncodingFilter' to: [/*]
2016-09-15 01:21:25.186  INFO 6672 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.c.embedded.FilterRegistrationBean  : Mapping filter: 'hiddenHttpMethodFilter' to: [/*]
2016-09-15 01:21:25.186  INFO 6672 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.c.embedded.FilterRegistrationBean  : Mapping filter: 'webRequestLoggingFilter' to: [/*]
2016-09-15 01:21:25.187  INFO 6672 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.c.embedded.FilterRegistrationBean  : Mapping filter: 'applicationContextIdFilter' to: [/*]
2016-09-15 01:21:25.324  INFO 6672 --- [           main] o.s.s.c.ThreadPoolTaskScheduler          : Initializing ExecutorService  'taskScheduler'
2016-09-15 01:21:25.649  INFO 6672 --- [           main] o.s.oxm.jaxb.Jaxb2Marshaller             : Creating JAXBContext by scanning packages [com.springintegration.example]
2016-09-15 01:21:26.207  INFO 6672 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter : Looking for @ControllerAdvice: org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@71a794e5: startup date [Thu Sep 15 01:21:21 CEST 2016]; root of context hierarchy
2016-09-15 01:21:26.284  INFO 6672 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/error],methods=[],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.Object>> org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.BasicErrorController.error(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest)
2016-09-15 01:21:26.285  INFO 6672 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/error],methods=[],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[text/html],custom=[]}" onto public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.BasicErrorController.errorHtml(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest)
2016-09-15 01:21:26.326  INFO 6672 --- [           main] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/webjars/**] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
2016-09-15 01:21:26.326  INFO 6672 --- [           main] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/**] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
2016-09-15 01:21:26.368  INFO 6672 --- [           main] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/**/favicon.ico] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
2016-09-15 01:21:26.741  INFO 6672 --- [           main] o.s.b.a.e.mvc.EndpointHandlerMapping     : Mapped "{[/trace],methods=[GET],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.EndpointMvcAdapter.invoke()
2016-09-15 01:21:26.742  INFO 6672 --- [           main] o.s.b.a.e.mvc.EndpointHandlerMapping     : Mapped "{[/mappings],methods=[GET],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.EndpointMvcAdapter.invoke()
2016-09-15 01:21:26.742  INFO 6672 --- [           main] o.s.b.a.e.mvc.EndpointHandlerMapping     : Mapped "{[/configprops],methods=[GET],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.EndpointMvcAdapter.invoke()
2016-09-15 01:21:26.742  INFO 6672 --- [           main] o.s.b.a.e.mvc.EndpointHandlerMapping     : Mapped "{[/autoconfig],methods=[GET],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.EndpointMvcAdapter.invoke()
2016-09-15 01:21:26.743  INFO 6672 --- [           main] o.s.b.a.e.mvc.EndpointHandlerMapping     : Mapped "{[/metrics/{name:.*}],methods=[GET],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.MetricsMvcEndpoint.value(java.lang.String)
2016-09-15 01:21:26.743  INFO 6672 --- [           main] o.s.b.a.e.mvc.EndpointHandlerMapping     : Mapped "{[/metrics],methods=[GET],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.EndpointMvcAdapter.invoke()
2016-09-15 01:21:26.744  INFO 6672 --- [           main] o.s.b.a.e.mvc.EndpointHandlerMapping     : Mapped "{[/env/{name:.*}],methods=[GET],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.EnvironmentMvcEndpoint.value(java.lang.String)
2016-09-15 01:21:26.744  INFO 6672 --- [           main] o.s.b.a.e.mvc.EndpointHandlerMapping     : Mapped "{[/env],methods=[GET],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.EndpointMvcAdapter.invoke()
2016-09-15 01:21:26.744  INFO 6672 --- [           main] o.s.b.a.e.mvc.EndpointHandlerMapping     : Mapped "{[/dump],methods=[GET],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.EndpointMvcAdapter.invoke()
2016-09-15 01:21:26.745  INFO 6672 --- [           main] o.s.b.a.e.mvc.EndpointHandlerMapping     : Mapped "{[/info],methods=[GET],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.EndpointMvcAdapter.invoke()
2016-09-15 01:21:26.745  INFO 6672 --- [           main] o.s.b.a.e.mvc.EndpointHandlerMapping     : Mapped "{[/beans],methods=[GET],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.EndpointMvcAdapter.invoke()
2016-09-15 01:21:26.745  INFO 6672 --- [           main] o.s.b.a.e.mvc.EndpointHandlerMapping     : Mapped "{[/health],methods=[],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.HealthMvcEndpoint.invoke(java.security.Principal)
2016-09-15 01:21:26.898  INFO 6672 --- [           main] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Registering beans for JMX exposure on startup
2016-09-15 01:21:26.916  INFO 6672 --- [           main] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Bean with name 'org.springframework.integration.channel.interceptor.WireTap#0' has been autodetected for JMX exposure
2016-09-15 01:21:26.917  INFO 6672 --- [           main] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Bean with name 'org.springframework.integration.channel.interceptor.WireTap#1' has been autodetected for JMX exposure
2016-09-15 01:21:26.921  INFO 6672 --- [           main] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Located managed bean 'org.springframework.integration.channel.interceptor.WireTap#0': registering with JMX server as MBean [org.springframework.integration.channel.interceptor:name=org.springframework.integration.channel.interceptor.WireTap#0,type=WireTap]
2016-09-15 01:21:26.941  INFO 6672 --- [           main] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Located managed bean 'org.springframework.integration.channel.interceptor.WireTap#1': registering with JMX server as MBean [org.springframework.integration.channel.interceptor:name=org.springframework.integration.channel.interceptor.WireTap#1,type=WireTap]
2016-09-15 01:21:26.952  INFO 6672 --- [           main] o.s.c.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor  : Starting beans in phase -2147483648
2016-09-15 01:21:26.952  INFO 6672 --- [           main] o.s.i.endpoint.EventDrivenConsumer       : Adding {service-activator:DBManager.handle.serviceActivator} as a subscriber to the 'dbchannel' channel
2016-09-15 01:21:26.952  INFO 6672 --- [           main] o.s.integration.channel.DirectChannel    : Channel 'application.dbchannel' has 1 subscriber(s).
2016-09-15 01:21:26.952  INFO 6672 --- [           main] o.s.i.endpoint.EventDrivenConsumer       : started DBManager.handle.serviceActivator
2016-09-15 01:21:26.953  INFO 6672 --- [           main] o.s.c.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor  : Starting beans in phase 0
2016-09-15 01:21:26.953  INFO 6672 --- [           main] ProxyFactoryBean$MethodInvocationGateway : started serviceIntegrationFlowConfiguration$EntryPoint
2016-09-15 01:21:26.954  INFO 6672 --- [           main] GatewayCompletableFutureProxyFactoryBean : started serviceIntegrationFlowConfiguration$EntryPoint
2016-09-15 01:21:27.015  INFO 6672 --- [           main] o.s.i.endpoint.EventDrivenConsumer       : Adding {logging-channel-adapter:_org.springframework.integration.errorLogger} as a subscriber to the 'errorChannel' channel
2016-09-15 01:21:27.015  INFO 6672 --- [           main] o.s.i.channel.PublishSubscribeChannel    : Channel 'application.errorChannel' has 1 subscriber(s).
2016-09-15 01:21:27.015  INFO 6672 --- [           main] o.s.i.endpoint.EventDrivenConsumer       : started _org.springframework.integration.errorLogger
2016-09-15 01:21:27.016  INFO 6672 --- [           main] o.s.i.endpoint.EventDrivenConsumer       : Adding {bridge} as a subscriber to the 'outputchannel' channel
2016-09-15 01:21:27.016  INFO 6672 --- [           main] o.s.integration.channel.DirectChannel    : Channel 'application.outputchannel' has 1 subscriber(s).
2016-09-15 01:21:27.016  INFO 6672 --- [           main] o.s.i.endpoint.EventDrivenConsumer       : started org.springframework.integration.config.ConsumerEndpointFactoryBean#0
2016-09-15 01:21:27.016  INFO 6672 --- [           main] o.s.i.endpoint.EventDrivenConsumer       : Adding {bridge} as a subscriber to the 'fileOutboundChannel' channel
2016-09-15 01:21:27.016  INFO 6672 --- [           main] o.s.integration.channel.DirectChannel    : Channel 'application.fileOutboundChannel' has 1 subscriber(s).
2016-09-15 01:21:27.017  INFO 6672 --- [           main] o.s.i.endpoint.EventDrivenConsumer       : started org.springframework.integration.config.ConsumerEndpointFactoryBean#1
2016-09-15 01:21:27.017  INFO 6672 --- [           main] o.s.i.endpoint.EventDrivenConsumer       : Adding {transformer} as a subscriber to the 'inputchannel' channel
2016-09-15 01:21:27.017  INFO 6672 --- [           main] o.s.integration.channel.DirectChannel    : Channel 'application.inputchannel' has 1 subscriber(s).
2016-09-15 01:21:27.017  INFO 6672 --- [           main] o.s.i.endpoint.EventDrivenConsumer       : started org.springframework.integration.config.ConsumerEndpointFactoryBean#2
2016-09-15 01:21:27.018  INFO 6672 --- [           main] o.s.i.endpoint.EventDrivenConsumer       : Adding {logging-channel-adapter} as a subscriber to the 'logChannel' channel
2016-09-15 01:21:27.018  INFO 6672 --- [           main] o.s.integration.channel.DirectChannel    : Channel 'application.logChannel' has 1 subscriber(s).
2016-09-15 01:21:27.018  INFO 6672 --- [           main] o.s.i.endpoint.EventDrivenConsumer       : started org.springframework.integration.config.ConsumerEndpointFactoryBean#3
2016-09-15 01:21:27.018  INFO 6672 --- [           main] o.s.i.endpoint.EventDrivenConsumer       : Adding {splitter} as a subscriber to the 'fileIntegrationFlow.channel#0' channel
2016-09-15 01:21:27.021  INFO 6672 --- [           main] o.s.integration.channel.DirectChannel    : Channel 'application.fileIntegrationFlow.channel#0' has 1 subscriber(s).
2016-09-15 01:21:27.021  INFO 6672 --- [           main] o.s.i.endpoint.EventDrivenConsumer       : started org.springframework.integration.config.ConsumerEndpointFactoryBean#4
2016-09-15 01:21:27.021  INFO 6672 --- [           main] o.s.i.endpoint.EventDrivenConsumer       : Adding {transformer} as a subscriber to the 'fileIntegrationFlow.channel#1' channel
2016-09-15 01:21:27.021  INFO 6672 --- [           main] o.s.integration.channel.DirectChannel    : Channel 'application.fileIntegrationFlow.channel#1' has 1 subscriber(s).
2016-09-15 01:21:27.022  INFO 6672 --- [           main] o.s.i.endpoint.EventDrivenConsumer       : started org.springframework.integration.config.ConsumerEndpointFactoryBean#5
2016-09-15 01:21:27.022  INFO 6672 --- [           main] o.s.i.endpoint.EventDrivenConsumer       : Adding {aggregator} as a subscriber to the 'fileIntegrationFlow.channel#2' channel
2016-09-15 01:21:27.022  INFO 6672 --- [           main] o.s.integration.channel.DirectChannel    : Channel 'application.fileIntegrationFlow.channel#2' has 1 subscriber(s).
2016-09-15 01:21:27.022  INFO 6672 --- [           main] o.s.i.endpoint.EventDrivenConsumer       : started org.springframework.integration.config.ConsumerEndpointFactoryBean#6
2016-09-15 01:21:27.023  INFO 6672 --- [           main] o.s.i.endpoint.EventDrivenConsumer       : Adding {service-activator} as a subscriber to the 'fileIntegrationFlow.channel#3' channel
2016-09-15 01:21:27.023  INFO 6672 --- [           main] o.s.integration.channel.DirectChannel    : Channel 'application.fileIntegrationFlow.channel#3' has 1 subscriber(s).
2016-09-15 01:21:27.023  INFO 6672 --- [           main] o.s.i.endpoint.EventDrivenConsumer       : started org.springframework.integration.config.ConsumerEndpointFactoryBean#7
2016-09-15 01:21:27.023  INFO 6672 --- [           main] o.s.i.endpoint.EventDrivenConsumer       : Adding {xml:marshalling-transformer} as a subscriber to the 'fileIntegrationFlow.channel#4' channel
2016-09-15 01:21:27.023  INFO 6672 --- [           main] o.s.integration.channel.DirectChannel    : Channel 'application.fileIntegrationFlow.channel#4' has 1 subscriber(s).
2016-09-15 01:21:27.024  INFO 6672 --- [           main] o.s.i.endpoint.EventDrivenConsumer       : started org.springframework.integration.config.ConsumerEndpointFactoryBean#8
2016-09-15 01:21:27.024  INFO 6672 --- [           main] o.s.i.endpoint.EventDrivenConsumer       : Adding {message-handler} as a subscriber to the 'fileIntegrationFlow.channel#5' channel
2016-09-15 01:21:27.024  INFO 6672 --- [           main] o.s.integration.channel.DirectChannel    : Channel 'application.fileIntegrationFlow.channel#5' has 1 subscriber(s).
2016-09-15 01:21:27.024  INFO 6672 --- [           main] o.s.i.endpoint.EventDrivenConsumer       : started org.springframework.integration.config.ConsumerEndpointFactoryBean#9
2016-09-15 01:21:27.024  INFO 6672 --- [           main] o.s.c.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor  : Starting beans in phase 1073741823
2016-09-15 01:21:27.027  INFO 6672 --- [           main] o.s.i.e.SourcePollingChannelAdapter      : started channelFileAdapter
2016-09-15 01:21:27.035  INFO 6672 --- [ask-scheduler-1] o.s.i.file.FileReadingMessageSource      : Created message: [GenericMessage [payload=D:\example_tex\in\dateeea.txt, headers={id=781992ab-70bb-4642-6954-4ca43b9101e2, timestamp=1473895287035}]]
2016-09-15 01:21:27.115  INFO 6672 --- [           main] s.b.c.e.t.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http)
2016-09-15 01:21:27.120  INFO 6672 --- [           main] c.s.e.FileIntegrationFlowConfiguration   : Started FileIntegrationFlowConfiguration in 6.154 seconds (JVM running for 6.688)
```

Comment: @Bean
 public IntegrationFlow fileIntegrationFlow(){
  return IntegrationFlows.from(readFilefromDirectory(), fileInboundPollingConsumer())
    .split(new FileSplitter())
    .transform(dataDataTransformer())
    .transform(Transformers.marshaller(getMarshaller(),resultTransformer(),true))
    .wireTap(logChannel())
    .handle(fileWriter()).get();

 }

Comment: Don't put code in comments - it's unreadable - edit your question instead.

Comment: Please, study this http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. It is out of good readability. I'll try to investigate your question, but that doesn't guaranty that I will be able to see the whole picture.

Comment: i have updated question

Comment: Answered. Cheers!

Comment: Interesting how would you like to get some help from us if you don't read your own edits?.. It's really difficult to help someone who doesn't respect your time and don't provide the proper information for analysis. Please, edit your question like you would like to see the answer.

Comment: How is my edit for you?

Comment: OK. You've just killed all my hard work... Sigh... And drop microphone

Comment: That answer was fine but only problem was with hard coding header and footer .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I think we should consider header and footer as messages to append as well.

`FileSplitter` can emit `FileMarker`s (`new FileSplitter(true, true)`), where `FileMarker.Mark.START` you can transform to the `header` message and, therefore, `FileMarker.Mark.END` to the `footer`.

Your `dataDataTransformer()` should take care about `FileMarker.Mark` transformation to the proper object XML String for downstream append.

I guess you will need `.filter()` for that purpose to bypass `.marshaller()` transformation, since you won't have a proper object from  `FileMarker.Mark` to marshal to valid XML.

For this purpose I'd do like this:

```
@Bean
public IntegrationFlow fileIntegrationFlow() {
    return IntegrationFlows.from(readFilefromDirectory(), fileInboundPollingConsumer())
            .split(new FileSplitter(true, true))
            .filter(p -> !(p instanceof FileSplitter.FileMarker.Mark), 
                        f -> f.discardChannel("convertToHeaderOrFooterChannel"))
            .transform(dataDataTransformer())
            .transform(Transformers.marshaller(getMarshaller(),resultTransformer(),true))
            .wireTap(logChannel())
            .channel("appendToFile")
            .handle(fileWriter()).get();    
}
```

The `.filter()` check a `payload` type and discard to the `convertToHeaderOrFooterChannel` for `Mark` transformation to desired String.

That `convertToHeaderOrFooterChannel` flow may look like:

```
@Bean
public IntegrationFlow markTransformationFlow() {
    return IntegrationFlows.from("convertToHeaderOrFooterChannel")
            .transform(...)
            .channel("appendToFile");    
}
```

Pay attention to the .channel("appendToFile") usage. This `markTransformationFlow()` sends its result to that channel, which is just before `fileWriter()` in the main flow!

**UPDATE**

According a new income about

> Final Xml file after all customer object added in file .

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<MonitoringData xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="java:java.lang.String">
    <customer><cust-name>33334444</cust-name></customer>
    <customer><cust-name>3333333</cust-name></customer>
</MonitoringData>
```

And data like `33334444` `3333333` I see the solution as `.aggregate()` to build `List<Customer>` and then `MonitoringData` as an outcome.

And only after that I'd marshal it fully and write to the file at once.

Comment: But actually headers are not coming readFilefromDirectory()  file , there is only data in txt file as  11111,22222 . we are reading row by row after splitting and then  creating a object as @XmlRootElement
public class Customer {
 
 private Long custId;
 private String custName;
 private String custDept;

Comment: Right, that's why I suggest to rely on the `FileSplitter.FileMarker.Mark` feature.

Comment: But header is part of object itself so should i hard code it for header and footer that i don't think a good idea. when object is marshalled then generated xml header i am talking but that object generates everytime means for every message

Comment: ??? That sound like a different story. Even if it relates to your question, it isn't obvious by your explanation.

Comment: OTOH, I don't understand how you are going to write several XMLs to one file without `root` element. That doesn't follow with XML specification. My idea to generate exactly `root` element for `Mark`s and the rest your items are just regular siblings in the target XML. So, let come back to the original task! What you have to do?

Comment: I have one object which consists list of customer object .i have to write xml for this where customer data is message which we are getting one by one@XmlRootElement
public class MonitoringData {
 
 List<Customer> customerList ;

 public List<Customer> getCustomerList() {
  return customerList;
 }

 public void setCustomerList(List<Customer> customerList) {
  this.customerList = customerList;
 }

}

Comment: Like this where <customer><cust-name>33334444</cust-name></customer>  we will get for every message .<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<MonitoringData xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="java:java.lang.String">
<customer><cust-name>33334444</cust-name></customer>
<customer><cust-name>3333333</cust-name></customer>
</MonitoringData>

Comment: Please, move that info into your question. It is fully impossible to read it from comments.

Comment: i have moved comment messages to question

Comment: Please, find an UPDATE in my answer.

Comment: Should i aggregate like this : @Bean
 public IntegrationFlow fileIntegrationFlow(){
  return IntegrationFlows.from(readFilefromDirectory(), fileInboundPollingConsumer())
    .split(new FileSplitter())
    .transform(dataDataTransformer())
    .wireTap(logChannel())
    .aggregate()
    .get();

 }

Comment: Yes, that's fine and then `.<List<Customer>>handle((p, h) -> new MonitoringData(p))` after `.aggregate()` and only after that `marshaller` and `.handle(writeToFile())`.

Comment: .<List<Customer>>handle((p, h) -> new MonitoringData(p)) this line in java 1.7 how can we write ?

Comment: Your code looks good for me. Any exceptions, logs on the matter?

Comment: In Logs we dont find anything only when i remove aggregator it works but same as old way.

Comment: Please, switch on `DEBUG` for the `org.springframework.integration` category and share logs how your messages are traveling.

Comment: And also. Doesn't your `dataDataTransformer()` return `Message` instead of just `Customer` object?

Comment: OK. Looks good. So, I wait for DEBUG logs to investigate from my side.

Comment: Well, I think the root of issue in the default `releaseStrategy` in the Aggregator which is based on the `sequenceNumber`. We don't have that value by default with `FileSplitter`. To meet its requirements you should switch off `iterator` mode for the `FileSplitter` - `new FileSplitter(false)`. In this case a `List` of file lines will be built and it is already sufficient for the default aggregator strategies.

Comment: Yes , when i changed new FileSplitter(false) then file is created but in my case i need to split file it is required as later i need to add one more flow in between (in data transformer ) where i will search data in some excel using some logic and then i will create customer object . Will this new FileSplitter(false) work in this case ?

Comment: Yes, it will. You still have there lines from file in the downstream flow.

Comment: Can i use filter between transformer and aggregator ? as i need to filter some data here ?

Comment: You can, but then default `releaseStrategy` isn't for you because after filtering you are not going to fit to the original `sequenceSize`. For this purpose I can suggest come back to the `FileSplitter.FileMarker` solution and make aggregator strategies based on the fact of arrival `FileSplitter.FileMarker.Mark.END`

Comment: Customised releasestrategy Example can you provide using java dsl